# Upgrading Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 with hidden comment code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am updating a site from Laravel 5.2 to (eventually) 5.7 that was coded by someone else.

Currently I having an issue with this type of code in a blade file:

```
{{-- */ $hidden = 'hidden' /* --}}
```

That creates a variable that is used in the file itself like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 {{$hidden}}" id="person1div">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

That seems to work fine in Laravel 5.2 but in 5.3 I get the error message:

```
Undefined variable: hidden
```

I could change the code to

```
<?php $hidden = 'hidden' ?>
```

but the issue is that there are many variables like this, used in various ways.

Something to note is that these variable are in loops which I guess is why the original developer used them as they get reset and re-populated.

Is there a  more correct way to populate the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select and replace the syntax like shown below.

You can set variables with values in blade file like this:

```
@php $hello = "Hello World!"; @endphp
```

and to print the variable on the blade file,

```
{{$hello}}
```

Comment: In these code-blocks would the trailing semi-colon be required?

Comment: If there will be 1 line of code, then it will work without semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Right, solved this (as often happens on SO) just after I posted this question.

I did a global find and replace and changed instances of

```
{{-- */
```

to

```
{!!
```

and also

```
/* --}}
```

to

```
!!}
```

So instead of

```
  {{-- */ $hidden = 'hidden' /* --}}
```

I have:

```
  {!! $hidden = 'hidden' !!}
```

That has done the trick.

Thanks for the answers - hope this helps someone else.

EDIT***********************************

Although I thought this was going to work for me as it turns out I kept on getting errors such as "Array to string conversion"

So I am going ahead with the answer from @himanshu-upadhyay